# Primefaces: actionListener doesn't work

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I build application with primefaces and use a commandbutton to call a rest service, in the method also redirect another page, in this page have a button with actionListener, but this doesn't execute the action.

The button in jsf after redirect (makeDevengo.jsf):

```
<p:commandButton value="View Devengo"
                            actionListener="#{devengosBean.showDevengo}">
                        </p:commandButton>
```

The initial button call (devengo.jsf):

```
<p:commandButton value="Make Devengo"
                    actionListener="#{devengosBean.newDevengo}">
                </p:commandButton>
```

The first method :

```
public void newDevengo(ActionEvent event) {



    try {

        // Rest call 
        //Redirection

        ExternalContext ec = context.getExternalContext();
        ec.redirect("/myPath/makeDevengo.jsf");
        return;



    } catch (Exception e) {
        context.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(
                FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Error",
                "Make devengo problem));
        LOGGER.error(e);
    }

}
```

The method never call:

```
    public void showDevengo(ActionEvent event) {

    System.out.println("--->showDevengo");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Be sure commandButton doesnt fire the method when you put breakpoint.
Be sure the second commandbutton is in a form.
Try addding update clause. If still doesnt work, share your whole codes.